# How to get percentage from how filled a pandas dataframe column is?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to determine how full each column in a .csv file is, add these to a list in order of how full each column is. The fullness should be expressed as a percentage.

The .csv file is really large, so it would be useful to determine which columns contain a small amount of data, and which contain the most. Therefore the columns that have more data will be more useful to me.

What I've gotten so far:

```
    import pandas as pd

    ranked_list = []
    csv_filepath = r"some_path_here"
    data = pd.read_csv(filepath)

    for column in data:
        way_to_calculate_percentage
        ranked_list.append(way_to_calculate_percentage)

print(sorted(ranked_list))
```

I would like to know if there is some way to determine this "way_to_calculate_percentage"

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check non missing values by [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) and count `mean` if need percentage of non missing values:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,np.nan,4,np.nan,np.nan,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,np.nan,7,1,0],

})

s1 = data.notna().mean()
print (s1)
A    1.000000
B    0.500000
C    1.000000
D    0.833333
dtype: float64
```

If need percentage of missing values use [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) with `mean`:

```
s2 = data.isna().mean().sort_values()
print (s2)
A    0.000000
C    0.000000
D    0.166667
B    0.500000
dtype: float64
```

Then is possible analyze values - with [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html),
[`Series.nsmallest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nsmallest.html) and if necessary use [`Series.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html):

```
s3 = s2.nlargest(2)
print (s3)
B    0.500000
D    0.166667
dtype: float64

s4 = s2.nsmallest(2)
print (s4)
A    0.0
C    0.0
dtype: float64

s5 = s2.sort_values()
print (s5)
A    0.000000
C    0.000000
D    0.166667
B    0.500000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi this seems to be working, but I am getting 0.000000 values for most of my columns. I suspect this is because the whole files isn't actually being read into pandas, as the file is 300MB big containing information about tropical cyclones in different columns. Do you have any ideas on how to not get so many 0 values?

Comment: @ShaunLowis - hmmm,  hard question, because deepnds of data. the best test in first 1k, 10k, 100k rows with `pd.read_csv(file, nrows=1000)`,  `pd.read_csv(file, nrows=10000)` and test if still 0 for no missing values.

Comment: Thank you, I think you answered my question comprehensively, I will see if I can get a workaround for the 0.000000 values at some stage. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following dataframe:

```
     a    b
0  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  NaN
2  2.0  NaN
3  3.0  4.0
```

You can calculate the percentage of each column like this:

```
null_percent = df.isnull().sum() / df.shape[0]
```

Result:

```
a    0.25
b    0.75
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
df
Out[13]: 
   ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
0    TypeA       A       a       x
1    TypeA       B     NaN       x
2    TypeA       C       b       x
3    TypeA       D     NaN       x
4    TypeA       E     NaN       x
5    TypeB       F     NaN       x
6    TypeB       A       g       x
7    TypeC       B     NaN       x
8    TypeC       Z     NaN     NaN
9    TypeC       C     NaN     NaN
10   TypeD       A       h     NaN

df.notna().sum()/len(df)*100
Out[14]: 
ColumnA    100.000000
ColumnB    100.000000
ColumnC     36.363636
ColumnD     72.727273
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi, I get a TypeError:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'method' and 'int'

Comment: can you share sample data? Also which line gives you that error?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is **memory footprint** which provides the usage size.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

dir_path = 'M:/Desktop/Python-Test/'
test_file = os.path.join(dir_path, 'test_file.csv')
pd1 = pd.read_csv(test_file)

print(pd1.memory_usage(index=False, deep=True))
```